# Generate a list of sheet names BUT EXCLUDE specific Worksheet in the List

Tags: vba, excel

I have a working macro right now that automatically generates a list of all the work sheets I have in my file:

```
Sub RefreshStocks()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim count As Integer

    For x = 4 To Worksheets.count

        Select Case Worksheets(x).Name
            Case "Calculator", "Index Composition", "Market Value", "Watch List", "REF DATA"
                'Do Nothing
            Case Else
                count = count + 1
                Cells(count, 2).Value = Worksheets(x).Name
        End Select

    Next x
End Sub
```

The macro is working fine, but I want to know what I should do if I have multiple worksheets that I want to exclude from the list. For example, if want to exclude the worksheets named "Reference data" and "Process Guide".

What I'm trying to do is to add an IF statement that has the sub ignore the worksheets named "Reference data" or "Process Guide" from the generated list.

```
Sub WSNames()
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 4 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheet.Name = "Reference data" Or "Process Guide" Then
            'IGNORE this Worksheet and should not be included
        Else
            Cells(x, 2).Value = Worksheets(x).Name
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Could someone help out to correct the code above.

[image]

Comment: IF Worksheet.name = "Reference data" or "Process Guide" then, just use IF Worksheet.name <> "Reference data" or "Process Guide" then  Cells(x, 2).Value = Worksheets(x).Name
        Next x., no need for any else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select case is ideal for this situation.

```
Sub WSNames()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim count as Integer
    count  = 4
    For x = 1 To Worksheets.Count

        Select Case Worksheets(x).Name
            Case "Reference data", "Process Guide"
                'Do Nothing
            Case Else
                Cells(count, 2).Value = Worksheets(x).Name
                count = count + 1
        End Select

    Next x
End Sub
```

Thanks YowE3K!

Comment: your codes is working. BUT there is a minor problem. It's excluding all the specified sheets that I asked to exclude but there the row was left blank. It supposed to generate a list without blank spaces between. But since we have excluded some sheets to be added in the list, the macro will leave it blank. I'll upload an image for your reference. See my updated question in awhile.

Comment: I updated my answer.  You did want to start from `Worksheet(4)`?

Comment: @ThomasInzina - I guessed that maybe Worksheets(1), (2), and (3) are "Sheets1", "Sheets2" and "Sheets3" and that they were being deliberately ignored.  But that would be better coded by processing all sheets and including those names in the list to be ignored.

Comment: Good advice @YowE3K.  I would exclude them by name, just in case, the worksheet order changes.

Comment: @ThomasInzina - I upvoted your answer as it now incorporates what I was doing.  (The only thing missing is an initialisation of "Count" - but I'm not sure whether the OP wants the list to start at row 1 or at row 4.  Original code would start it at row 4.)

Comment: @YowE3K nice attention to detail.  I'm going to leave my answer **as is** because the OP said it "Worked!" and it's an obvious adjustment for the OP.  I also gave you the +1.

Comment: @ThomasInzina, sorry for not getting back to you yesterday. I just encountered a minor glitch. the list is suppose to display 8 sheet names but it only shows 6. I'm not sure why. I have updated the code in my question using your own code with few modifications.

Comment: another thing, the list was generated in Cell B1. In my previous code, I want the list to be generated at Cell B4. which was working. Im not sure what happened, but it think the culprit is this line Cells(r, 2).Value = Worksheets(x).Name

Comment: I just updated my code.  I should have initiated the count variable to 4; so that the code would start in B4.  The missing worksheet names is probably due from starting at worksheet 4.  I change it to start from `Worksheets(1)`. Any sheets that aren't worksheets will not show up in the worksheet collection.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub WSNames()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    r = 3
    For x = 4 To Worksheets.Count
        IF Worksheets(x).name = "Reference data" or _
           Worksheets(x).name = "Process Guide" then 
            'IGNORE this Worksheet and should not be included
        Else
            r = r + 1
            Cells(r, 2).Value = Worksheets(x).Name
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

I included a new variable, r, so that there wouldn't be gaps in your list where the excluded worksheet names would have otherwise been.

Comment: @BenDaggers - I noticed you attempted to edit my answer to include the image you added to your question.  I rejected the edit, as I assume you tried to add it in here by accident.  I hope that doesn't give you any negative reputation points.

Comment: No worries. I was using mobile when I upload it. Might have tapped the wrong link. its suppose to edit my answer. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 0):

just use `if worksheet(x).name<>"ref data" and worksheet(x).name<>"Proc guide" then`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub WSNames_another()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If sh.Name = "Reference data" Or sh.Name = "Process Guide" Then
            'IGNORE this Worksheet and should not be included
        Else
            'Do what every you want
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub WSNames()
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 4 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(x).Name = "Reference data" Or Worksheets(x).Name = "Process Guide" Then
            'IGNORE this Worksheet and should not be included
        Else
            Cells(x, 2).Value = Worksheets(x).Name
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```